# To retrieve the forgot password

Tags: php, codeigniter

In the below code i have used codeigniter code i enter username and password to db.but i want to retrieve my forgot password .I tried but i got the following errors pls help to recify the issue.

Controller:

```
<?php

class Login extends CI_Controller {

    function index()
    {
        $data['main_content'] = 'login_form';
        $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);      
    }

    function validate_credentials()
    {       
        $this->load->model('membership_model');
        $query = $this->membership_model->validate();

        if($query) // if the user's credentials validated...
        {
            $data = array(
                'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
                'is_logged_in' => true
            );
            $this->session->set_userdata($data);
            redirect('site1/members_area');
        }
        else // incorrect username or password
        {
            $this->index();
        }
    }   

    function signup()
    {
        $data['main_content'] = 'signup_form';
        $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);
    }

    function create_member()
    {
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        // field name, error message, validation rules
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('first_name', 'Name', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('last_name', 'Last Name', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email_address', 'Email Address', 'trim|required|valid_email');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|min_length[4]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|min_length[4]|max_length[32]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password2', 'Password Confirmation', 'trim|required|matches[password]');
         $this->load->helper('date');

        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $this->load->view('signup_form');
        }

        else
        {           
            $this->load->model('membership_model');

            if($query = $this->membership_model->create_member())
            {
                $data['main_content'] = 'signup_successful';
                $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);
            }
            else
            {
                $this->load->view('signup_form');           
            }
        }

    }
    public function forgot_password()
{
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email_address','Email Address','trim|required|valid_email|callback__check_email_exists');

    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
       // VALIDATION ERRORS, SHOW VIEWS
       $this->index();
    }
    else
    {
      // ALL IS GOOD, UPDATE EMAIL, AND REDIRECT TO CURRENT URL
      $this->load->view('login_form');
    }
}
public function _check_email_exists($email)
{
  // LOAD AND USE YOUR MODEL TO CHECK EMAIL EXISTS HERE
  if ( ! $email_exists )
  {
    $this->form_validation->set_message('email_address', 'That email address don\'t exist, sucka!');
    return FALSE;
  }
  else
  {
    return TRUE;
  }
}
    function logout()
    {
        $this->session->sess_destroy();
        $this->index();
    }

}
```

model

```
<?php

class Membership_model extends CI_Model {

    function validate()
    {
        $this->db->where('username', $this->input->post('username'));
        $this->db->where('password', md5($this->input->post('password')));
        $query = $this->db->get('membership');

        if($query->num_rows == 1)
        {
            return true;
        }

    }

    function create_member()
    {

        $new_member_insert_data = array(
            'first_name' => $this->input->post('first_name'),
            'last_name' => $this->input->post('last_name'),
            'email_address' => $this->input->post('email_address'),         
            'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
            'date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', now()),
            'password' => md5($this->input->post('password'))                       
        );

        $insert = $this->db->insert('membership', $new_member_insert_data);
        if ($this->db->_error_number() == 1062)
                {
                echo"<script>alert('This value already exists');</script>";
                }
                if ($this->db->_error_number() == "")
                {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('create', 'create');
                }

        return $insert;
    }


    public function val_forgot_password()
{
    $this->db->where('email_address', $this->input->post('email_address'));
    $query = $this->db->get($this->members);

    if($query->num_rows == 1)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
    function curdate() {
    // gets current timestamp
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila'); // What timezone you want to be the default value for your current date.
    return date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
}
}
```

view:login_form

```
<?php $this->load->view('includes/header'); ?>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/style1.css"  />
<div id="login_form">

    <h1>Login!</h1>
    <?php 
    echo form_open('login/validate_credentials');
    echo form_input('username', 'Username');
    echo form_password('password', 'Password');
    echo form_submit('submit', 'Login');
    echo anchor('login/signup', 'Create Account');
    echo form_close();
    ?>

</div><!-- end login_form-->


<?php $this->load->view('includes/footer'); ?>
<?php

echo form_open('login/forgot_password');
echo "Email Address: " . form_input('email_address', set_value('email_address', ''));
echo br(2);
echo form_submit('submit','Send Email');
echo form_close();
echo br(1);

echo validation_errors('<p>Error: ');

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all you will need a function in the controller to bring the user to a forgot user page.

```
public function forgot_pass(){
 $this->load->view('forgot_pass_view');
}
```

Then you will probably need to ask atleast for the email address in the view.
Create another function to verify the email address in the controller, and if it matches send a mail with a new temporary password.

```
public function check_email(){
  $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
  $this->load->library('form_validation');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'email_check', 'callback_email_check');
  if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
   //throw error
  } else {
   //send email
  }
}
public function email_check(){
  //use this function to check if the email exists and return false if it is not the DB
}
```